# Process Order via OpenCart addOrder method

Tags: php, opencart

The following function is being called as confirmed when I echo $test_text in the template file.

Php is not yelling at me either (anymore), but the "order" is not processing.

```
    public function process_cart() {
        $this->load->model('sale/order');
          $this->data['test_text'] = "I'm here."
          $order_details = array(
                'store_id' => 1,
                'customer_id' => $this->address['customer_id'],
                'customer_group_id' => 1,
                'firstname' => $this->address['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $this->address['lastname'],
                'email' => $this->address['email'],
                'telephone' => $this->address['telephone'],
                'fax' => $this->address['fax'],
                'payment_firstname' => $this->address['firstname'],
                'payment_lastname' => $this->address['lastname'],
                'payment_company' =>  '',
                'payment_company_id' =>   '',
                'payment_tax_id' =>   '',
                'payment_address_1' =>   '',
                'payment_address_2' =>   '',
                'payment_city' =>   '',
                'payment_postcode' =>   '',
                'payment_country_id' =>   '',
                'payment_zone_id' =>   '',
                'payment_method' =>   '',
                'payment_code' =>   '',
                'shipping_firstname' =>   '',
                'shipping_lastname' =>   '',
                'shipping_company' =>   '',
                'shipping_address_1' =>   '',
                'shipping_address_2' =>   '',
                'shipping_city' =>   '',
                'shipping_postcode' =>   '',
                'shipping_country_id' =>   '',
                'shipping_zone_id' =>   '',
                'shipping_method' =>   '',
                'shipping_code' =>   '',
                'comment' =>   '',
                'order_status_id' =>   1,
                'affiliate_id' =>   '',
                'products' => $this->data['products']
                );

        $this->model_sale_order->addOrder($order_details);
    }
```

Can anyone see see what I'm missing?

Comment: How and from where is this method called? What is it's class? Are you sure that after calling this method you have no errors in (OpenCart's) PHP log or that there is no _empty_ order created in DB?

Comment: The class is ModelSaleOrder in model_sale_order (admin/model/sale/order) page and empty orders ARE being placed - they are just not coming up with the customer name in them. So obviously I am not sending the correct information or not sending it correctly. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @MikeiLL Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: i must have, but not sure exactly how. i don't even have a process_cart() function anymore. just seeing process_carts(). Here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/zxkrCjLR from admin/cart/checkout (which is a mod). in admin/controller/sale/checkout I have http://pastebin.com/WiznN5v7. Please let me know if either are of any use. I'm thinking maybe processing single cart wasn't the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
$order_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product SET

                             order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', 
                             product_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "', 
                             name = '" . $this->db->escape($product['name']) . "', 
                             model = '" . $this->db->escape($product['model']) . "', 
                             quantity = '" . (int)$product['quantity'] . "', 
                             price = '" . (float)$product['price'] . "', 
                             total = '" . (float)$product['total'] . "', 
                             tax = '" . (float)$product['tax'] . "', 
                             reward = '" . (int)$product['reward'] . "'");

        $order_product_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option SET 

                                order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', 
                                order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "', 
                                product_option_id = '" . (int)$option['product_option_id'] . "', 
                                product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option['product_option_value_id'] . "', 
                                name = '" . $this->db->escape($option['name']) . "', 
                                `value` = '" . $this->db->escape($option['value']) . "', 
                                `type` = '" . $this->db->escape($option['type']) . "'");
        }

        foreach ($product['download'] as $download) {

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download SET 

                                order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', 
                                order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "', 
                                name = '" . $this->db->escape($download['name']) . "', 
                                filename = '" . $this->db->escape($download['filename']) . "', 
                                mask = '" . $this->db->escape($download['mask']) . "', 
                                remaining = '" . (int)($download['remaining'] * $product['quantity']) . "'");
        }   
    }

    foreach ($data['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_voucher SET 

                            order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', 
                            description = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['description']) . "', 
                            code = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['code']) . "', 
                            from_name = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['from_name']) . "', 
                            from_email = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['from_email']) . "', 
                            to_name = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['to_name']) . "', 
                            to_email = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['to_email']) . "', 
                            voucher_theme_id = '" . (int)$voucher['voucher_theme_id'] . "', 
                            message = '" . $this->db->escape($voucher['message']) . "', 
                            amount = '" . (float)$voucher['amount'] . "'");
    }

    foreach ($data['totals'] as $total) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET 

                            order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', 
                            code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', 
                            title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', 
                            text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', 
                            `value` = '" . (float)$total['value'] . "', 
                            sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
    }   

    return $order_id;
```

try this one add after your existing code.